# Show user details without saving in previous session

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

what code do I need to put in this (profile.php) file so I can echo the information of the user that has been logged in. I have a HTML code after this where I want to display the information. I can already echo the username because thats been saved in the login.php session. Is there an option to echo the other information without adding any other code in the login.php?

```
// This is the profile.php file
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['username']) || empty($_SESSION['username'])){
header("location: login.php");
exit;
}
?>

//DB = users with id, username, firstname, lastname etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, what the process for this is that instead of saving the username in the session, you store the unique ID for each account and fetch the information based on the ID.

This way, you only need to store the ID and you can get all the information easily.

However, with your current setup, you'd run a simple query to select the user information from your db table based on the username saved in the session.

I would've provided some code but you've not provided any database information so I can't really guess your table names so I can't really mock out a query.

**Update #1**

I'm going to assume that you are a proficient developer who's using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) (*hint: use them if you aren't*):

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` = ?
```

Then you'd bind and fetch the data and output it. Obviously, you don't need to use `*` and you can provide your own columns.

**Note:** Ensure that your usernames are unique otherwise, add `LIMIT 1` but even then, you might get the wrong record, hence I suggested the user of an ID above.

Comment: I have heard that a lot of times but I don't know how to work with that. Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: You'll need to provide more details such as table names and what you are using to connect to MySQL for me to provide some pseudo-code.

Comment: I have added DB. Please check.

Comment: I connect DB with config.php $link = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

Comment: Please can you work these information in my code above so I can understand a bit more and know where to start. Thanks!

Comment: No. Not to sound harsh but sufficient information has been provided for you to complete this that is, if you put your head to it. If you need clarification with your new attempts, do say. It just seems as though you want the code written for you and that I will not do.

Comment: Okok haha you have not understand me but no problems. I understand you. I will look into it and get back here when I run into problems